# Create a custom layout/view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view

[image: Sample]

I have already designed the xml layout for this view but its view hierarchy is very deep,for example the root layout is a relative layout which contains a card view.The root within this card view is a relative layout which contains an image to the right( taylor swift) and a text view at the bottom.the left portion containing details is a linear layout (vertical) with each row in turn being a linear layout (horizontal) containing the icon (share) and the text.
Is there a better way of doing this or should i use a custom layout,if so how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/person_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/call_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/call"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/call"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_36dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="98984968468"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
                android:background="@color/grey" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/email"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_36dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="abc@gmail.com"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
                android:background="@color/grey" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sms_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sms"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_36dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sms_num"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="987544244"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/anniversary_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_p" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person_1_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_1_image"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="User name"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: First time I see TS in this site. . . There are many ways you can.. you can do Custom views extending the RelativeLayout class.. or just stay in inflating that xml everytime you need it...

Comment: i have actually never written a custom view before and would like to learn,could you provide a few good sites or places to learn that if you know any.

Comment: The Javadocs of Android.. in Android developers site.. if you extend the classes, with average understanding of View and ViewGroup hierarchies, you can manipulate a View

Comment: What does the root RelativeLayout provide? What happens if the card view is the root? Otherwise, the rest sounds like the way I would implement what you have shown, except maybe RelativeLayout inside the vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: please add your xml layout to question

Comment: use array adapter  for this or make another custom layout

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can remove a lot of your layout hierarchy.
It looks like you should be able to have a CardLayout as the root.
Then a RelativeLayout as the sole child of the CardLayout.
And then, everything else as a direct child of the RelativeLayout.

You should be able to position everything in the RelativeLayout
using relative positioning, without having to resort to more embedded layouts.

I don't see how a custom layout would help, and given that you've never written
one before, I think it would be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: added the xml layout,could you show what elements can be removed while still preserving the final layout.